# Copy all of the values of text box to another text box

Tags: javascript

I have two fields. There are multiple text boxes inside of each fields. I would like to copy all of the text values from the box 1 to box 2 without putting up the specific target for each text boxes. Here is my markup and my js code.

```js
$('[name="copy"]').click(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        if ($(this.checked)) {
            $('#box2 input').val($(this).val());
        } else {
            $('#box2 input').val('')
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" value="Default"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" value="Value"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" value="Here"/>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div id="box2">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-checkbox">
  <label>Copy the text values of Textbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="copy" />
</div>
```

Comment: What is `this.checked` supposed to be? A text box can't be checked.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: And why are you putting `this.checked` inside `$(...)`? `this.checked` is `true` or `false`, it does't make sense to convert that to a jQuery object.

Comment: I'm not sure with what I'm doing. I'm still playing around with javascript. I've added a checkbox, where it will only copy the text values if the checkbox is checked and `.checked` should be `true` I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop over the corresponding inputs will do the job:

```js
$('[name="copy"]').click(function(){
  // get a list of all text fields in the first div 
  var ins = $('#box1 input[type="text"]');

  // get a matching list of all text fields in the second div 
  var outs = $('#box2 input[type="text"]');
  
  // look at each item in the list(s) (they're the same length)
  for ( var i = 0; i < ins.length; ++i )
    // for each one, if the checkbox is checked, set the second box's 
    // input value to the matching value from the first
    //
    // if it's unchecked, empty out the second box's input's value
    //
    outs[i].value = this.checked ? ins[i].value : '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box1">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox11" value="Default"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox12" value="Value"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox13" value="Here"/>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div id="box2">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox21" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox22" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox23" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-checkbox">
  <label>Copy the text values of Textbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="copy" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.each` passes the index of the element to the function. You can use this to update the corresponding element of the other DIV.

You also need to test `this.checked` outside the `.each()` loop, because inside the loop `this` refers to the current element of the loop, not the checkbox that you clicked on.

```js
$('[name="copy"]').click(function(){
    var copy = this.checked;
    $('#box1 input[type="text"]').each(function(i){
        if (copy) {
            $('#box2 input').eq(i).val($(this).val());
        } else {
            $('#box2 input').eq(i).val('')
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" value="Default"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" value="Value"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" value="Here"/>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div id="box2">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-checkbox">
  <label>Copy the text values of Textbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="copy" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[name="copy"]').click(function(){
    var originalTextboxes = $('#box1').find('input[type="text"]');
    var copyTextboxes = $('#box2').find('input[type="text"]');
  
    if (this.checked) {
      originalTextboxes.each(function(i){
        $(copyTextboxes[i]).val($(this).val());
      });
      
    } else {
      copyTextboxes.each(function() {
        $(this).val('');
      });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="box1-textbox1" value="Default"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="box1-textbox2" value="Value"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="box1-textbox3" value="Here"/>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div id="box2">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 1: </label>
    <input type="text" id="box2-textbox1" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 2: </label>
    <input type="text" id="box2-textbox2" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Textbox 3: </label>
    <input type="text" id="box3-textbox3" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-checkbox">
  <label>Copy the text values of Textbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="copy" />
</div>
```

Each ID must be unique though it has no direct bearing on the solution. As someone else noted, input fields do not have a "checked" state so it needs to be moved out of that "each" loop.

In this case, since the two sets of inputs are in discrete containers, all you have to do is loop through the first set and apply the values to the applicable input in the second set.